# geoserver cross-layer cql filter with feature id

Tags: geoserver

I want to get the features of layer A that have intersection with a specific feature in layer B (using the id of the feature in layer B). below is my query:

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=sf:roads,sf:restricted,sf:bugsites&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG:26713&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;INCLUDE;INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('sf:restricted', 'the_geom','IN('restricted.4')'))&BBOX=589081.6705629,4914128.1213261,609174.02430924,4928177.0717971&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=358
```

but the query cannot be parsed and I receive this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I fixed it...
I used two single quotations around the id and it works fine :| (one double quotation doesn't work).

```
INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('sf:restricted', 'the_geom','IN(''restricted.4'')'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the query that gets the feature from the second layer (`querySingle('sf:restricted', 'the_geom','IN('restricted.4')')`)

The 3rd argument should be the `where` clause, including the field name and the desired value. As you are looking for a single ID, it could be `'ID=4'`

Have a look at the [example page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html), the ID field for `sf:restricted` is `cat`

```
querySingle('sf:restricted', 'the_geom','cat = 4')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The field 'cat' is not the id. its a property. I have a few layers that don't have a property with unique values like the 'cat' property... There is an example in geoserver documation to extract the features with specific ids but it is not working with crosslayer filter http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#id-and-list-comparisons